# Chromium handling of confirm dialog in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, chromium

I am testing the `confirm()` JS call in chrome browser on Android (similar to [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_confirm)). I observe that the dialog displayed is very similar to Android's `AlertDialog` class.

I wanted to ask if Chromium handles the `confirm()` JS call using Android's `AlertDialog`. If yes, is this [file](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/lkcr/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/JavascriptAppModalDialog.java#81) the right place where they handle it ? (I cannot tell for sure)

Comment: Yes, chromium uses native views for such sings  - the place you are pointing on is correct one. The question is do you want to edit chromium browser directly?

Comment: I do want to play around with Chromium browser code.