# Window confirm() behavior in Chromium vs WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, chromium

I am trying to test the window `confirm()` [method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) in Android Webview. I am running a Android 7 build (custom build). WebView in this build is not Chrome, but seems to be based on chromium (I haven't changed any webview code in the build). The developer options in settings indicate that the build is using `Android WebView`. (Note: the test below can be also be done on a Nexus 5X API 24 emulator using Android Studio)

I tested the `confirm()` method and I see different behavior (UI) in webview compared to a chromium browser. A quick test is on this [page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_confirm).

When I test it in the `chromium browser` (downloaded using the [getChromium](https://github.com/andDevW/getChromium) app on GitHub or F-Droid), I observe the following behavior (the behavior is consistent with the Chrome browser):

[image]

I asked a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059096/chromium-handling-of-confirm-dialog-in-javascript) before and it seems they are using Android's `AlertDialog` to show this UI.

I then tested the same page in the `webview browser tester` app and I see the following behavior:

[image]

I want to ask if `WebView` implementation is based on Chromium, then:

1. Why is the UI different for dialog in the two cases ?
2. Is the second case also leveraging Android's `AlertDialog` underneath (e.g. using a custom layout in the dialog) ?

Comment: So what is the `webview browser tester app`? On what device/emulator/OS version are you testing on. Are you aware that webview sources changed with Android 5.0 Lollipop:  https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Comment: The webview browser tester app comes preinstalled in the Nexus images run via Android Studio. I am aware of the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a second test wherein I created a app with a WebView inside and loaded the page with the `confirm()` method. This time the UI looked similar to Chrome / Chromium browsers. This shows that WebView based on chromium had consistent results.

I think the issue was my use of the `webview browser test` app that was preinstalled in the Android Studio Nexus 5X image. I think that app may have done some customization in its use of WebView.